# How to modify toolbar in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

In idea intellij i want to remove `git options` from editor toobar and add debug option to its place.

How can this is done?

---

git options to remove

[image]

debug options to add

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it using `Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Menus and Toolbars`:
[image]

Comment: It does not work for me, even when I remove "VCS Actions" there, it stays in the toolbar (and even after reloading IntelliJ).
It did work when I removed it from "Navigation Bar Toolbar".